# Slick slider hangs sliding while ajax events on going in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

We have mobile horizontal navigation in Slick Slider.
And the simple tab(In) structure using Bootstrap.
Slick Slider with v

We load the contents of the menu bar items using AJAX requests meanwhile we display Skeleton loading for that menu items.

But a slick slider hangs while the ajax requests are still ongoing.

Once all the requests complete Slick Slider working perfectly fine.

Does anybody face a similar issue?